# How To Change Color Of Text In Middle Of String Using Javascript Or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm certain this is a simple problem, but i cannot find how todo this.

```
<p><span="test1">This is some test</span> text to color.</p>
```

I need to change the color of the "to color" characters using javascript or jquery. I cannot alter the html adding classes or ids.

I have looked at creating element nodes, but cant get it to work.

Comment: *I cannot alter the html* - at least you should be able to wrap a text with a `<span>` tag

Comment: So... how static that html is? what is the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [html-function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function):

```js
$('p').html(function(i, txt) {
  return txt.replace('to color', '<span style="color: red;">to color</span>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><span id="test1">This is some test</span> text to color.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can do it with css assuming `<p>` has no other children that would be affected and you are wanting to change anything not in span

```
p {
   color: red 
}

p > span {
  color: black
}
```

The other option is you must wrap the text in another element using script and set color on that element.